# PostgreSQL substring

Tags: postgresql, substring

I have a function and I want to get a string between two strings where the first one is "Start" and the second one is the new line character.

I mean: From "Start blablabla \n" I only want "blablabla".

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
select substring(test from 'Start(.+)\n') into vtest;
```

How can I identify the newline character??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be double-escaped:

```
test=> select substring('foo
bar' from E'\\A(.*)\\r?\\n');
 substring 
-----------
 foo
(1 row)
```

Alternative version:

```
select substring('foo
bar' from E'\\A.*(?=\\r?\\n)');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$` symbol matches the string end:

```
select substring('Start123' from 'Start(.+)$'); 
 substring 
-----------
 123
```